# How to make QLineEdit emit the previous and the current text in a textChanged signal

Tags: c++, qt, subclassing

I want to subclass `QLineEdit` to emit a new signal which will have the text from the moment it got focus and the new text.

like:

```
Signals:
  void customTextChanged(const QString& previousText , const QString& currentText);
```

The purpose of this `QLineEdit` is to edit the name of an item, in case it exists it disables the `Ok_button` ( this is done in the `on_text_changed(QString)` slot).

I want to check if the user changed his mind and did set the previous name or he undoed.

Comment: Subclass, override `focusInEvent` in which you can copy the current text in a member variable, self-connect `textChanged` to a slot of yours in which you do the comparison, and emit signals to say whether the line edit has actually been modified or not?

Comment: @peppe care to formulate this as an answer? If not T.Zak:  it is not wrong when there has not been an answer already to write what you did (with some details/code) as an answer to your own question and accept it

Answer (score 3):

Thanks to [peppe](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1873944/peppe).

The following subclass stores the `lineEdit` text when **focused** ,then whenever the text is **changed** checks if the text is the same as the text at the start and if it is not it emits a `textEditedCustom(QString)`.

goes to header!

```
class customQLineEdit: public QLineEdit
{
  Q_OBJECT
public :
  explicit customQLineEdit(QWidget* parent = 0 );
  explicit customQLineEdit(const QString &str, QWidget* parent=0);

signals:
  void textEditedCustom(const QString& text);

public slots:
  void on_Text_Edited_custom(const QString& currentText);

protected:
  QString previousText;
  virtual void focusInEvent(QFocusEvent* e);
};
```

and the .cpp part

```
customQLineEdit::customQLineEdit(QWidget* parent ):
  QLineEdit(parent)
{
  connect(this , SIGNAL(textEdited(QString)) ,
          this , SLOT(on_Text_Edited_custom(QString)));

}

customQLineEdit::customQLineEdit(const QString &str, QWidget* parent):
  QLineEdit(str , parent)
{
  connect(this , SIGNAL(textEdited(QString)) ,
          this , SLOT(on_Text_Edited_custom(QString)));

}


void customQLineEdit::focusInEvent(QFocusEvent* e)
{
  previousText = text();
  QLineEdit::focusInEvent(e);
}

void customQLineEdit::on_Text_Edited_custom(const QString& txt)
{
  if(previousText !=  txt)
    emit textEditedCustom(txt);
}
```

Then you subscribe to it like this:

```
connect( nameLineEdit , SIGNAL(textEditedCustom(QString)) , 
          this , SLOT(on_nameLineEdit _Changed(const QString &)));
```

Comment: Note that there is no focus-in-event if you make programmatic changes with setText(). In this case this does not work.